# Can't get this memory addressing

Tags: exploit-development

I am working with this INE eCXD material and I am working on my basics of buffer overflow on Linux.
In the lab, there is supposed to be a binary that is using the `strcpy()` function and it SEGFAULTS when it reaches that function.
I loaded the binary in GDB-PEDA and set a breakpoint at `strcpy()`.

When I run the binary it pauses at my breakpoint.
but when I view the registers it shows up like the below image.

[image]

At this point I am supposed to investigate starting from the ESP.

What I don't get it is why does the ESP ( and of course the other registers) looks like that ? 
`ESP: 0xffffd2cc --> 0x8048493 (add    esp,0x10)`
Isn't the ESP supposed to hold one address, so what does it mean when in looks like that?

One more thing: 
When I read the write up, I found that they examined the `0x8048493` as a return address which I didn't get, but I am going along with it at the moment.
They started examining the address using this instruction 
`x/20i 0x08048493-20` [Which basically means examine 20 instructions starting from the mentioned address].
The result was: 
[image]

By mistake I entered the below instruction: 
`x/20i 0x08048493` [dropped the 20]

which resulted in the below results

[image]

I want to know why both of the results are different, isn't it supposed to mean to examine the  next 20 instructions starting from the given address.

Answer (score 2):

So I just started learning this stuff last week and I've been using raw gdb not this cooler looking one, so take this with a grain of salt if you will. Anyone else can correct me if I'm wrong.

For your first question, the ESP does hold one address, which from that picture is **0xffffd2cc**. It looks like this:
`ESP: 0xffffd2cc --> 0x8048493 (add    esp,0x10)` because the ESP is currently pointing to address **0xffffd2cc**, which the address of a pointer to **0x8048493**, which contains the instruction **(add    esp,0x10)**

---

For your second question, it *does* mean examine the next 20 instructions starting from the given address. The command is `x/20i <starting address>`, and in your first picture the starting address is **0x08048493-20**, which
**0x08048493-0x14 = 0x0804847f**.

In your second picture you forgot the **-20**, so the starting address is just **0x08048493**. If you compare everything just after the `strcpy@plt` in your first picture at address **0x0804848e**, you'll find that the rest of the instructions are identical.